# Jsf primefaces and Spring Boot project component inject problem

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

I have a working JSF and Spring Boot application. I want to communicate to having custom spring scope beans. Application context is JSFContext. When I use @Autowired annotation, new Bean comes and run @PostConstruct method  multiple times that is not what I have expect.

I try more than way for Bean inject. 
`FacesContextUtilitiy.WebApplication(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance).getBean("myBean")` again return me new Bean.

```
@Component("facultativeTreatyDefinitionBean")
@Scope("view")
public class FacultativeTreatyDefinitionController {
```

bean definition.

```
@Component("addressBean")
@Scope("view")
public class AddressController { 
@Autowired
@Qualifier("facultativeTreatyDefinitionBean")
private FacultativeTreatyDefinitionController facultativeTreatyDefinitionController;
```

My expectation is that; bean in the same scope should communicate without bean creation.

what do you think is the problem

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] and edit it into your question.

Comment: Then your custom scope is not working . And if the coded way does not work, your question is not primefaces (nor jsf) related and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging